# What will this method return, true or false?

Tags: c#

```
bool isValid = false;
string username = "someadmin";

If( !String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !( username.IndexOf("admin") != -1)
    isValid = true;
```

The second part with the double negatives is crossing me up!

Comment: ... well, considering that we can't see the return statement, I don't think we can answer the question ;-]

Comment: Why ask us? You have the code right there -- run it and see!

Comment: This code will not compile. Unmatched parens.

Comment: `username.IndexOf("admin") != -1` is the same as `username.Contains("admin")` which is easier to parse mentally

Comment: 1) this isn't a method. 2) it has several syntax errors

Comment: It won't compile.  You're missing a ')'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will return false

```
!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)          // this is true, the string is not NullOrEmpty
!(username.IndexOf("admin") != -1)       // IndexOf is >= 0, so != 1 is true. But the first ! makes it false
```

So IsValid will contain the same value as it had at the beginning...

Comment: "IndexOf is >= 0" - not quite, indexof can also be -1.
"The zero-based index position of value if that string is found, or -1 if it is not."

Comment: Lol, i was making some fastly readable code perfectionist. username.IndexOf("admin") >= 0 is actually the case. I was typing faster than I could think about the fact if the return value should be 4 or 5. That's what the computer is for i guess... But luckily the questioner was helped with my answer ;)

Answer (score 10):

May I present to you [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

```
NOT (P OR Q) = (NOT P) AND (NOT Q)
NOT (P AND Q) = (NOT P) OR (NOT Q)
```

So, you could rewrite it as:

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || username.IndexOf("admin") != -1)) {
    isValid = true;
}
```

...thus removing the double negatives.

Furthermore, you could say:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || username.IndexOf("admin") != -1) {
    isValid = false;
}
```

...which removes all the negatives.

Also, you could say:

```
isValid = !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || username.IndexOf("admin") != -1));
```

...to make it nice and compact.

Comment: DeMorgan is great and all, but haven't you now required the username to contain `"admin"`?

Answer (score 1):

It'll return false.

Answer (score 1):

A plain language version:

if (username is not null or empty    and   username doesn't contain "admin")
   isValid = true;

Answer (score 0):

`isValid` will be false.

(Nitpick: this code doesn't "return" anything: it just sets the value of the `isValid` variable.)

Answer (score 0):

false. But I don't get the question? Couldn't you just execute this? What double negatives? The value is just being inverted and the parentheses clearly indicate the order in which the statements are executed.

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in `isValid` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a syntax error due to a missing paren ;-)

But seriously, it will return false.

!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) // if username is NOT null and NOT empty => true

username.IndexOf("admin") != -1 // if "admin" IS FOUND in username (not -1) => true

!( username.IndexOf("admin") != -1 ) // if "admin" IS NOT FOUND in username => false

So, concluding: the conditions of the if statement are NOT met, so isValid will remain false.

PS.: I'm not a c# programmer, but I presume that when IndexOf(string) equals -1, it means not found.